# Are the F-18 movements in the Top Gun: Maverick movie really possible?

Tags: fighter, aerobatics, maneuver, dogfighting, aviation-in-fiction

Lately, I watched the new movie Top Gun: Maverick. A few times Maverick made some impressive movements when he was getting hunted by another fighter jet. He somehow goes slightly up, brakes and gets behind the jet.

I tried to find a look-a-like image to show the movement. Here you can see a screenshot of the [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=giXco2jaZ_4) on YouTube, which shows the movement of getting behind a fighter jet:

[image]

So I was wondering if it is really possible to get behind a fighter jet like this way?

Comment: It is called Cobra Manoeuvre and can be performed for sure by some fighters (Saab Draken for example).

Comment: Yes, it's the cobra. Many fighters can do it but among F-18s only one modified aircraft is capable (NASA F-18 High Alpha Research Vehicle (HARV)).

Comment: @user3528438 I think some kind of AoA protection prevents most fighters from being able to perform this manoeuvre.  The diversion manoeuvre of the second fifth-gen fighter looks like a very tight Herbst manoeuvre instead (?)

Comment: Similar to 'VIFFing' in the Harrier. Looks great, practically no combat application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Cobra maneuver" is primarily an airshow stunt. To my knowledge it has never been performed or verified in actual combat.

Comment: At least not successfully, because it presents a *huge* target for the other plane’s guns.

Comment: @StephenS Assuming the other pilot even has guns.